# Java 8 Stream - .max() with duplicates

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

So I have a collection of objects that have a step variable that can be 1 - 4.

```
public class MyClass {
    private Long step;

    //other variables, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

`Collection<MyClass> myOjbects = /*get collection*/;`

Then I would like to get one instance of `MyClass` from the collection that has the maximum step value, so I do:

```
final Optional<MyClass> objectWithMaxStep =
   myObjects.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getStep));
```

However, there are situations where there will be multiple `MyClass` instances in the collection that have a step equal to 4.

So, my question is, how is it determined which instance is returned in the `Optional`, or does it throw an exception when multiple objects in the stream have the max value that is being compared?

The Java 8 documentation for the `max()` function does not specify what will occur in this situation.

Comment: Why does the order matter if they are equal?

Comment: For the particular example I'm using it for, it doesn't really matter, since I am only pulling the step from the returned object. However, there are other variables in the class, so being on the same step does not mean the objects are equal. So in other situations, it might matter which object is returned. The reason for my question was mainly to understand how the `max()` function works when multiple objects have the same value in the field being compared.

Comment: And why not just use a chained comparator including those other variables if they matter?

Comment: I would use a custom comparator that took into account multiple variables if they mattered. They don't matter in this case. I was merely interested in how the `max()` function determined which object to return. My code works fine. I'm not trying to solve a problem, rather understand what is happening.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`max` is implemented reducing the collection with `maxBy`:

```
 public static <T> BinaryOperator<T> maxBy(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(comparator);
        return (a, b) -> comparator.compare(a, b) >= 0 ? a : b;
    }
```

Here `comparator.compare(a, b) >= 0 ? a : b` you can see that when 2 elements are equal, i.e. `compare` returns 0, then the first element is returned. Therefore in your case will be returned *first* in a collection `MyClass` object with highest `step`.

**UPDATE:** As user [the8472](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1362755/the8472) correctly mentioned in comments, you shouldn't rely on implementation which isn't explicitly specified by javadocs. But you can write unit test on `max` method to know if it's logic has changed in standard java library.

Comment: as long as the javadocs don't specify behavior you shouldn't really rely on the implementation.

Answer (score 10):

Since the ordering isn't specified by the documentation, then the order can be different in future versions of the JVM or in different implementations of the JVM.

If you care which one is returned then my advice is to write your own reduction operation or Collector to behave however you desire.  That way future implementations can't change it and you can explicitly say what will happen.

Comment: There's a connection here to the behavior of `sorted()` and `distinct()`.  The sort operations are stable if the stream is ordered, and not stable otherwise.  Analogously, the `distinct` operation returns the _first_ instance of each equivalence class if the stream is ordered.  And reduction also respects encounter order if the stream is ordered.  What's missing is that min/max don't commit to this - but arguably they should.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Do you think it likely that future versions will commit to things like this? A similar issue I have is with `Collectors.toList()` which doesn't commit to the type or even the mutability of the returned `List`. It would be really nice to have guarantees for this sort of thing.

Comment: The two examples couldn't be more different.  There's a reasonable argument that the min/max thing is just an oversight, and therefore there's a chance we might correct that.  The `toList()` thing wasn't an oversight -- it was the whole point!  So there's zero chance we'd change that.  The complete lack of commitment is by design -- to maximize implementation flexibility.  (And we included easy alternatives.  If you want an `ArrayList`, you can use `toCollection(ArrayList::new)`.)