# Java 8 Way of Adding in Elements

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

Is there a more concise, perhaps one liner way, to write the following:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    myList.add(i);
}
```

Using Java 8 features, and functionally insipred approaches. I'm not expecting a Haskell solution like:

```
ls = [1..100]
```

But something more elegant than the traditional imperative style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

The steps:

1. `IntStream.range(0, 100)` is a stream of 100 primitive `int`s.
2. `boxed()` turns this into a stream of `Integer` objects. This is necessary to put the numbers into a `Collection`.
3. `collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));` is how you convert a `Stream` to an `ArrayList`. You can replace `ArrayList::new` by any supplier for a collection, and the elements will be added to that collection.

Comment: Can you explain each step in the "pipeline"?

Comment: @Michael Which step don't you understand? Did you check its documentation?

Comment: To be honest, the whole expression. I've never seen `IntStream` before, but especially the part starting with `boxed` onward @Pshemo

Comment: @PaulBoddington You can replace `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` with `Collectors.toList()` since it internally is using ArrayList (at least in current version http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#Collectors.toList%28%29).

Comment: @Pshemo I know, but I don't recommend people to do that if they want a mutable collection as Brian Goetz told me in a comment that the implementation may change. I'll see if I can find the link.

Comment: @Pshemo Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790372/java-8-stream-max-with-duplicates where Brian Goetz answers my query on this.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Thanks. I've seen it earlier and that is why I added "at least in current version" :)

Comment: They simply probably don't see any reason to guarantee immutability and it is good thing to have some flexibility for future designs. Honestly I never faced any need for it myself, but I don't work with Java on daily bases so that is just my private opinion which can change in the future.

Comment: @Michael. *"I've never seen IntStream before"* - but there's plenty of documentation. If you paste the code sample into an IDE you should even get all the javadocs on mouse-hover. You will have to understand them eventually anyway, so reading the docs now rather than later would be a good use of everyone's time.

Comment: @Pshemo, structural immutability can be beneficial if they return an empty list for example. if you can't add to it then they can just always return `Collections.emptyList()` thus reducing footprint - at the cost of polluting type profiles with varying types. Then, taking it a step further and always returning immutable lists (and special-casing an empty immutable list of the same type) would restore clean type profiles.

Comment: Currently, collectors don’t know the stream size, even if the stream has a predictable size. Thus, collecting into an `ArrayList` is not the best choice as it might require expensive capacity increasing and the decision to do it this way might be the result of time pressure. A future version might collect into a spined buffer (or a similar structure) and return an immutable `List` wrapper to get rid of the internal array copying operations. But since the OP never explicitly stated that the list must be mutable, I guess, it doesn’t need to be an `ArrayList` and `Collectors.toList()` would be ok