# Java 8 Stream - Find largest nested list

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Collection<List<SomeObject>> values`

How can I find the collection with the largest list using Streams?

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't quite work

```
values.stream().max(e -> e.stream().max(List::size).get()).get()
```

But I get compilation error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you want

```
 values.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size)).get()
```

If you need duplicates, the best solution I can think of would be something like

```
values.stream()
   .collect(Collector.of(
      ArrayList::new,
      (List<List<SomeObject>> best, List<SomeObject> elem) -> {
        if (best.isEmpty()) {
          best.add(elem);
        } else if (best.get(0).size() < elem.size()) {
          best.clear();
          best.add(elem);
        }
      },
      (best1, best2) -> {
        if (best1.isEmpty() || best2.isEmpty()
              || best1.get(0).size() == best2.get(0).size()) {
          best1.addAll(best2);
          return best1;
        } else if (best1.get(0).size() > best2.get(0).size()) {
          return best1;
        } else {
          return base2;
        }
      }));
```

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out before you answered :)

Comment: One problem I get is that my maximum has two entries. So I should have gotten both results, however it only chooses the first I guess. How can I get the max, but also duplicates?

Comment: @ShervinAsgari See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334404/how-to-force-max-to-return-all-maximum-values-in-a-java-stream/29334774

Comment: I found out why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790372/java-8-stream-max-with-duplicates. Seems I cant use sort if I want duplicates

Comment: I suppose you could probably write a special-cased `Collector` for it, but that would be hard.

Comment: @ShervinAsgari my answer now provides a `Stream`-based solution that works in a single pass, though it does take a fair amount of work.

Comment: I doubt you tested it because it doesn't compile since the collect method you are using requires a BiConsumer as combiner. Also it seems you missed to add the list in your accumulator if its size is the same as the max size already stored. Anyway the implementation in the linked question is far more reusable.

Comment: @AlexisC. I'm fine with that.  No, I didn't test it.

Answer (score 3):

My [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library provides a ready [collector](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#maxAll-java.util.Comparator-) to find all the maximal elements:

```
List<List<SomeObject>> result = values.stream()
                .collect(MoreCollectors.maxAll(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size)));
```