# Find max size of an element among list of objects

Tags: java, java-stream

```
@Data
class Person {

    private String fname;
    private String lname;

    private List<String> friends;
    private List<BigDecimal> ratings;

    ...
}

@Data
class People {

    private List<Person> people;

    ...
}
```

suppose i have the above classes, and need to figure out what is the most number of friends any one person has. I know the pre-streams way of doing it... by looping over every element in the list and 
checking if friends.size() is greater than the currently stored number of longest list. is there a way to streamline the code with streams? something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776248/java-8-stream-find-largest-nested-list)?

Comment: Yes, you can... But you don't have a nested list, do you?

Comment: Stream people, map to `person.getFriends()` which will convert to `IntStream` then you can find `max`.

Comment: Do you have a `List<People>`?

Comment: `people.stream().mapToInt(p -> p.getFriends().size()).max()`

Comment: Do you want max no of friends or the person with max no of friends?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compute the max `Person` contained in `People` according to a comparator that relies on the size of `Person.getFriends()` :

```
Optional<Person> p = people.getPeople()
                           .stream()
                           .max(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getFriends()
                                                           .size()));
```

Note that you could also retrieve only the max of friends without the Person associated to :

```
OptionalInt maxFriends = people.getPeople()
                               .stream()
                               .mapToInt(p -> p.getFriends()
                                               .size())
                               .max();
```

Comment: 1) favour `Comparator.comparingInt` instead of `Comparator.comparing` when comparing ints. 2) the last one can be significantly improved to `OptionalInt max = people.getPeople().stream().mapToInt(p -> p.getFriends().size()).max();`

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the following method in `Person` class:

```
public int getNumberOfFriends(){
   return friends.size();
}
```

and then use it in a stream like this:

```
Optional <Person> personWithMostFriends = people.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getNumberOfFriends));
```

With this approach you will get the `Person` object with the most friends, not only the maximum number of friends as someone suggested.

Comment: favour `Comparator.comparingInt` instead of `Comparator.comparing` when comparing ints

Comment: Also, avoid calling `get()` straight from an optional result unless you're sure the source is _definitely_ not empty. leverage the `orElse`, `ifPresent` et al.

Comment: @Aominè Yeah, I should've mentioned that. Thank you.

Comment: I understand up-voting / accepting another correct answer, but down-voting another correct answer ..why?

Answer (score 1):

Your question already answered. but i add this for one thing. if your list of person size **large** and if you have **multi-core pc** and you want to used this efficiently then use **parallelstream()**.

To get person:

```
Person person = people.getPeople()
.parallelStream()
.max(Comparator.comparingInt(p-> p.getFriends().size()))
.orElse(null);
```

To get size:

```
int size = people.getPeople()
.parallelStream()
.mapToInt(p -> p.getFriends().size())
.max().orElse(0);
```

Comment: `.orElse(null)` defies the purpose of `Optional`. At least use `orElse(0)` since you're working with `int`s.