# Java find biggest size of list in list

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collections, java-stream

I want to find the biggest size() of `List<TileFrame>` tileFrames that is inside of `List<TileAnimation>` class.

TileAnimation.java

```
public class TileAnimation {
private long localGID;
private List<TileFrame> tileFrames;

public long getLocalGID() {
    return localGID;
}

public void setLocalGID(long localGID) {
    this.localGID = localGID;
}

public List<TileFrame> getTileFrames() {
    return tileFrames;
}

public void setTileFrames(List<TileFrame> tileFrames) {
    this.tileFrames = tileFrames;
}

public TileAnimation(long localGID, List<TileFrame> tileFrames) {
    this.localGID = localGID;
    this.tileFrames = tileFrames;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TileAnimation{" +
            "localGID=" + localGID +
            ", tileFrames=" + tileFrames +
            '}';
}
}
```

TileFrame.java

```
public class TileFrame {
private long tileId;
private long duration;

public long getTileId() {
    return tileId;
}

public void setTileId(long tileId) {
    this.tileId = tileId;
}

public long getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(long duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

public TileFrame(long tileId, long duration) {
    this.tileId = tileId;
    this.duration = duration;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TileFrame{" +
            "tileId=" + tileId +
            ", duration=" + duration +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Let's say I have such list of objects and I filled it later on:

```
private List<TileAnimation> tileAnimations = new ArrayList<>();
```

then how to find such max size in inner `List<TileFrame>` of `List<TileAnimations>` ?
All the solutions I know when there are just one list with sigular fields without inner lists, but here it is something new for me and I could not find any solution in the internet of such issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 Stream - Find largest nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776248/java-8-stream-find-largest-nested-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve it simply by using streams

```java
int maxTileFramesSize = tileAnimations.stream()
       .mapToInt(tileAnimation -> tileAnimation.getTileFrames().size())
       .max()
       .orElse(0);
```

Comment: Seems ok. Tommorow I will test it out and mark your answer as accepted. Thank you :)