# Compare BigDecimals List to a specific value and return closest value

Tags: java, java-stream, bigdecimal

I have a List of Big Decimal Values and also a specific input also a BigDecimal. I want to compare the specific input against the values in the List and select the value that is closest to specific input. Any suggestions please?

```
    private static BigDecimal getWageMultiplier(List<BigDecimal> values, BigDecimal valueAmount) {

    values.sort(BigDecimal::compareTo);

    int index = values.indexOf(valueAmount);

    // Check for an exact match and if not get the index of the previous value
    if (index == -1) {

        // start with the highest index, in case there is no higher value than the previous
        index = values.size() - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            //work out the value from the List<BigDecimal> values that is closest to BigDecimal valueAmount
        }
    }

    int finalIndex = (index);

    return finalIndex != -1 ? values.get(finalIndex) : BigDecimal.ZERO;
}
```

Comment: Since you have a sorted list, you need to calculate the insertion point at which the inputted value would be inserted into the current list, this would give you the previous lowest and next highest values. Maybe a form of binary search could help

Comment: Is the list long and an efficient algorithm the target of the exercise? [mcve] Sample values and output, a runnable Mockobject would be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could achieve this comparing the absolute differences between each value in the list and the given value:

```
public static BigDecimal findClosest(List<BigDecimal> list, BigDecimal value) {
    return list.stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparing(a -> value.subtract(a).abs()))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Empty collection"));
}
```

Comment: This is working well, however if I pass a value in of 3.5 is rounding down to 3 even if both 3 & 4 are in the Big Decimal List. Assuming I would need to add in logic for Rounding Half up for the BigDecimal value?

Comment: @devC Read [this question and the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790372/java-8-stream-max-with-duplicates). It states that in case of duplicates (as defined by the `Comparator`), the first of them will be returned. Hence, it depends whether the `min` encounters `3` or `4` first. Both are equal in the eyes of the comparator (distance to 3 is 0.5). You could adapt the `Comparator` to handle this special case where `value` is x.5 to favor numbers larger than `value`. But beware, what about a list containing `2.9` and `4.1`, or `2` and `5`? Should it still favor higher ones?

Comment: An example for an improved `Comparator`: Add `.thenComparing(a -> value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).subtract(a).abs())` to the current one. In case two numbers have equals distance to `value`, it will compare them again to the rounded `value`. In your example, it will then return `4`.

Comment: Reversing the list.stream allows values half way between two values to round up.

return list.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())

Comment: Reversing works if you sort your list/stream, but will not be guaranteed if it is not sorted or the `min` parallelises. I'd recommend relying on a stricter `Comparator` and the min-reduce. It makes the sorting of the list/stream unnecessary, which might cause quite a performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by iterating over the list and use BigDecimal functions such as subtract and abs(absolute value). The following solution takes O(N). 
Note: this solution is not using java 8. Of course we can solve it using Java 8.

```
private static BigDecimal getWageMultiplier(List<BigDecimal> values, BigDecimal valueAmount) {

        BigDecimal minDifference = values.get(0).subtract(valueAmount).abs();
        int index = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i < values.size(); i++) {

            BigDecimal difference = values.get(i).subtract(valueAmount).abs();

            if(difference.compareTo(minDifference) < 0) {
                minDifference = difference;
                index = i;
            }
        }

        return values.get(index);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast solution for long lists, splitting the size into halfs:

```
int getMinDist (List<Integer> values, int target) {
    if (values.size () == 1) return values.get (0); 
    int mid = values.size ()/ 2;
    int left= Math.max (0, mid -1);
    int v0 = values.get (left); 
    int v1 = values.get (mid);
    // println (left + " " + mid + " | " + v0 + " " + v1);
    int av0 = Math.abs (target - v0);
    int av1 = Math.abs (v1 - target);
    return (av0 <= av1) ? getMinDist (values.subList (0, left+1), target) : getMinDist (values.subList (mid, values.size ()), target);
}

List<Integer> vals = Arrays.asList (1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 18, 19) 

-> getMinDist (vals, 16)
2 3 | 5 9
1 2 | 17 18
0 1 | 9 17
|  Expression value is: 17
|    assigned to temporary variable $86 of type int

-> getMinDist (vals, 4)
2 3 | 5 9
0 1 | 1 3
0 1 | 3 5
|  Expression value is: 3
|    assigned to temporary variable $87 of type int
```

Replace int with BigDecimal for your case is left as an excercise.

Instead of splitting the List, passing indexes for lower, upper, starting with 0 and list.size()-1 in the beginning, might even be better.